# AppleScript: Handler for Calling Shell Scripts Results in "Unrecognized function fileHandleForReading"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bash, applescript

When handler `doProcess_` is called, the script fails and results in target output:

```
2012-12-09 22:59:24.193 cma[76284:303] *** -[cmaAppDelegate doProcess:]: unrecognized function fileHandleForReading. (error -10000)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
script cmaAppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"
property inputUser : missing value
property inputPass : missing value
property outPipe : missing value
property outFileHandle : missing value
property theResult : missing value

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

on doShellScriptInBackground_callback_(theCommand, selectorName)
    -- create pipe for standard output, and get reading file handle from it tell current application's NSPipe to set outPipe to pipe()
    set outFileHandle to outPipe's fileHandleForReading()
    -- make task and launch it
    tell current application's NSTask to set theTask to alloc()'s init()
    tell theTask
        setLaunchPath_("/bin/sh")
        setArguments_({"-c", theCommand})
        setStandardOutput_(outPipe)
        -- the following line is needed or logging ceases at this point setStandardInput_(current application's NSPipe's pipe())
    end tell
    -- add observer for notification
    tell current application's NSNotificationCenter to set nc to defaultCenter()
    tell nc to addObserver_selector_name_object_(me, selectorName, current application's NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification, outFileHandle) -- launch task
    tell theTask to |launch|()
    -- tell file handler do its stuff in the background
    tell outFileHandle to readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify()
end doShellScriptInBackground_callback_


on dataIsReady_(notif)
    -- remove the observer
    tell current application's NSNotificationCenter to set nc to defaultCenter()
    tell nc to removeObserver_name_object_(me, current application's NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification, missing value) -- get the data from notification's userInfo dictionary
    set theData to notif's userInfo()'s valueForKey_("NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem")
    -- make it into a string
    set theResult to current application's NSString's alloc()'s initWithData_encoding_(theData, current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    -- do something wih the result
    log theResult
end dataIsReady_

on doProcess_(sender)
    doShellScriptInBackground_callback_("ls -ltr", "dataIsReady:")
end doProcess_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "set outPipe to current application's (NSPipe's pipe())" in order to call "outPipe's fileHandleForReading()"

Change:

```
on doShellScriptInBackground_callback_(theCommand, selectorName)
    -- create pipe for standard output, and get reading file handle from it tell current application's NSPipe to set outPipe to pipe()
    set outFileHandle to outPipe's fileHandleForReading()
```

To:

```
on doShellScriptInBackground_callback_(theCommand, selectorName)
    -- create pipe for standard output, and get reading file handle from it
    tell current application's NSPipe to set outPipe to pipe()
    set outFileHandle to outPipe's fileHandleForReading()
```

That's it. I tested it, and it worked for me. It seems you just have amended that line to the comment above.

Just to be thorough; that line can be written many ways:

```
tell current application's NSPipe to set outPipe to pipe()
```

is the same as

```
set outPipe to current application's (NSPipe's pipe())
```

and

```
tell current application's NSPipe
    set outPipe to pipe()
end
```